# Flutter - OnTap does not work in InkWell() and GestureDetector() functions

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

The screen is output as desired.
However, when I press a location on the screen, onTap does not work in InkWell() and GestureDetector() functions.

OnTap didn't work even though I used InkWell() function instead of GestureDetector() function

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FutureBuilder<double>(
            future: whenNotZero(Stream<double>.periodic(Duration(microseconds: 100),
                (x) => MediaQuery.of(context).size.width)),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
                return Scaffold(
                  appBar: AppBar(
                    title: Text(widget.title),
                  ),
                  body: Column(
                    children: [
                      InkWell(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              width: 8,
                            ),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                          ),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
                          child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_sharp),
                                Text("Text1"),
                              ]),
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          print("I am InkWell");
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            });
      }
    
      // ignore: missing_return
      Future<double> whenNotZero(Stream<double> source) async {
        await for (double value in source) {
          if (value > 0) {
            return value;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

please advice

Alex Hwang

Comment: I have tested your code and seems to work OK? How are you testing?

Comment: I tested your code too and it worked fine.